# When using POI, should I use read in an excel sheet as a Workbook or as a HSSFWorkbook?

Tags: apache-poi

I have to create a custom tag that uses POI to read in an excel file, modify some cells, and then write the modifications back to the same excel file.  There are multiple sheets in the excel file.  In some of the sheets, certain cells are locked, some cells have color coding, and some cells have drop down options.  When I write the modifications back to the excel file, all these special styles must remain the same.

I noticed that I can read in an excel file as a `Workbook` by doing `WorkbookFactory.create()`.  I can also read in as a `HSSFWorkbook` by doing `new HSSFWorkbook()`.  My question is, which one should I use for what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook` is the common interface that applies for HSSF (.xls files) and XSSF (.xlsx files). By using `Workbook` instead of `HSSFWorkbook`, your code can work just the same for both file format.

From the [*Why Change?* section on the POI website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html#Why+change?):

> If you have existing HSSF usermodel code that works just fine, and you don't want to use the new OOXML XSSF support, then you probably don't need to. Your existing HSSF only code will continue to work just fine.
>
> However, if you want to be able to work with both HSSF for your .xls files, and also XSSF for .xslx files, then you will need to make some slight tweaks to your code.

So, if you only need to support .xls, and only ever with, you can stick with `HSSFWorkbook`. However, if you want to work with both .xls and .xlsx, either now or in the future, use the common interfaces